# How to add Relative layout in Relative layout dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

My project file has `XML` like root `xml`. In root `xml` i define a `Relative layout` like below

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root_view">
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I have another `xml` file first is `one.xml` and another is `two.xml` like below

**one.xml**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/two_video_layout">

             <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/two_video_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="Video Title" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

and another layout is

**two.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/two_video_layout">

                 <Imageview
                        android:id="@+id/image"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

How can we add `one.xml` or `two.xml` dynamically in `root.xml` with certain condition and how can access reference of textview of `one.xml` file

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the view using LayoutParams.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

    parentView.addView(linearLayout, relativeParams);
```

To relatively position your items programmatically you have to assign ids to them.

```
TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tv1.setId(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,
where rootLayout is for root.xml

```
RelativeLayout two_video_layout=new RelativeLayout(this);
rootLayout.addView(two_video_layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)  like this :

```
LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewYou_want_to_inflate, null);
// to inflate one.xml call 
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one, null);
TextView textView=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.two_video_title); // to get textview object from one.xml
// to inflate two.xml call 
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.two, null);
```

and to add a view in a root view call `addView` function like this  :

```
RelativeLayout root_layout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.root_view);
layout.addView(v);
```